# Why is there a limitation on the number of points a polygon can have on ST_WITHIN?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are at a cross roads where we need to decide if we are going to store our GeoSpatial data in DocumentDB or SQL Azure. According to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/), the polygon parameter of the `ST_WITHIN` function in a query can contain a maximum of 256 points. Our data will potentially contain polygons with millions of points as we are mapping continents, countries, states/provinces, etc. We need to be able to use `ST_WITHIN` against all of these polygons. The article also mentions that we can adjust that limitation by contacting Azure Support.

Why is this limitation in the first place? If Support does remove the limitation, are we going to bring DocumentDB down with so many points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes, they are worried you will bring DocumentDB down with more than 256 points.  It used to be limited to just 16 points, but they changed it to 256 recently. Perhaps they will raise it again in the future. We ran into a similar problem with polygons having more than 1,000 points. In the end, we decided to use Sql Server for our polygon searches and then use the data refined from Sql Server to pull the related data from DocumentDB.

The problem is that DocumentDB resources are shared between customers so all of the operations that you run against DocumentDB have to be governed by request units. That way, no one customer can bring the system down with massive queries. I don't know how to calculate the request units from using ST_WITHIN on millions of points, but my guess is that even on the S3 tier, it would probably push the limit of the allowable 2500 Request Units.  So even if they lifted the 256 points to a one million points, your query might not be able to finish because it would be too expensive.  So I suggest you go with Sql Azure. That is what we settled on and it performs great.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it all in DocumentDB (as opposed to adding something like SQL Azure), you can use an approach of narrowing down the list by using ST_DISTANCE to get candidates and then running the equivalent to ST_WITHIN client side (ray casting algorithm is simple and fast). The trick involves storing denormalized meta-data about each polygon, namely a center point (accuracy of center point not critical) and the maximum radius using that center point. Then if the distance between your point and the center minus the maximum radius is less than zero, it's in the candidate list. It works like a charm and is performant with some careful index design.

One thing to worry about is the condition where the polygon intersects itself. Do you treat the intersecting space as outside the polygon or within it? We had a nasty bug that took forever to figure out and it boiled down to a self-intersecting polygon. This problem exists whether you implement your own algorithm or use the database's native "within" function.

Comment: Thank you for your work around, definitely something to consider